# Change taskbar hover/selection color Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, colors

I want to change the hover/selection color in the Windows taskbar.

**Motivation**: Better visibility during keyboard control / navigating with TAB key

**How it looks now**:
[image: Taskbar where MS Word is selected with TAB key (Win10Pro)]

**How it is supposed to look**:
[image: Taskbar where MS Word is selected with TAB key (Win10Enterprise]

In fact, these images are from my two computers running Win10. They have different Windows Versions (Pro / Enterprise).

**Does anyone know how to change this color?**

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color by going to `Settings` -> `Ease of Access` -> `High Contrast`

Then enabling it at the top. Here you can change the color for selection which will affect the selected item color for the taskbar too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I suppose you mean `ease of access` instead of `accessibility`.

I do not think that this is the solution though.

 Reason 1: When high-contrast is on, this changes everything, not just the
   selection color.

Reason 2: On the computer I got the "How it is supposed to look" screenshot, high-contrast is off.

Comment: Any other suggestions anyone?